# Get URL for an image from an MVC solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to add inside my web (REST API) project a folder and an image and send a URL back to the browser that it can be used to load that image. I am using MVC and C#. Any idea?

Comment: You can create an ASHX handler to handle the image request and send the image to the client. You can find an example here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

Comment: i try to use System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory to create that directory and StreamWriter to write that image. Problem no privilages but when i try to use a simple StreamReader with "imageExample01.jpg" that is inside my project StreamReader try to read from ISS is directory

Comment: @itsme86, an ASHX handler? are you kidding? since ASP.NET MVC 1.0 we no longer use ASHX handlers

Comment: @Miguel Garcia Boriani, please sow us the code you are using. Where does the image come from?. Are you getting any error?

Comment: You will definitively need write permissions on the parent directory where you are going to create your new directory and write de image.